# event id returned from Microsoft graph api not working correctly

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am experiencing an issue that looks like it has been answered in the past.  I have an calendar event id that was returned from the search api of the graph api.  The id contains forward slashes.  In another post it says to replace the forward slashes with %2E2F.  I tried that and it still doesn't work for me.
Below i have copied the HitId retruned from the search API, and the Request to retrieve the actual event, which fails with an object not found.  To verify I used the url below in Microsoft graph explorer and I get the same error as I do in my application.

Can someone help please?

Original ID: AAMkADgwZjlhNmJjLWNiMGQtNGE5MS1hMDVkLTNkNTU2ZWE5ZmM5ZgFRAAgI2fcomcHAAEYAAAAAI6tH+gq1iUqCeqCnGG6yXwcAMq9gls1/Qkq1+34H69QBTgAAAAABDQAAMq9gls1/Qkq1+34H69QBTgAFW9CKNwAAEA==

Changed ID: /v1.0/me/events/AAMkADgwZjlhNmJjLWNiMGQtNGE5MS1hMDVkLTNkNTU2ZWE5ZmM5ZgFRAAgI2fcomcHAAEYAAAAAI6tH+gq1iUqCeqCnGG6yXwcAMq9gls1%252FQkq1+34H69QBTgAAAAABDQAAMq9gls1%252FQkq1+34H69QBTgAFW9CKNwAAEA==

the URI above does not work in graph explorer. Can someone help. Thanks

Share
Edit
Delete
Flag

Comment: Whatif there is an issue with the URL itself, so copying the URL from your application and testing it in Graph Explorer is not a possible one. Outside of your application, I would suggest you to use the entire flow (Graph API calls) in Microsoft Graph Explorer or POSTMAN and see if you can repro the issue. Also share the previous issue reported in past helps as well.

Comment: thank you for your comment.  But I figured it out.  If I replace the / with a - as suggested by someone else it works perfectly.  I have no explanation of why.

Comment: Cool, thats nice. @Kevin, thanks for updating it back. It will be useful to others in the community as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a post to another StackOverflow question, I replaced the `/` with `-` and the queries now work. It is not a great solution, but it works.